# printing out tree rules computed from R's randomForest package

Tags: r

I'm using R's randomForest package. Is there a way for me to figure out the splitting rules used at each node in the computed trees?

Sample code:

```
library(randomForest)
mydata = data.frame(output = factor(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), x = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), y = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
mydata.rf = randomForest(output ~ ., data = mydata, ntree = 3)
```

I suspect it has something to do with `mydata.rf$forest$treemap`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, answered it myself: I can use the `getTree` function, described in the pdf documentation.